# why does javascript document.write not work on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

i have an html page displaying an image. it is supposed to delay, change to the video, then after the video plays, change back to the image. this is the javascript i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function playVideo(){
var str='**html of the video object**';
document.open();
document.write(str);
document.close();
}
function backToImage(){
var str='**html of the image**';
document.open();
document.write(str);
document.close();
}
setTimeout("playVideo()",1000);
setTimeout("backToImage()",3000);

</script>
```

this javascript works in Chrome and Safari. It mostly works in IE (the second timeout does not work, but i just discovered this). It does not work at all in Firefox. There is no delay, the video simply begins playing and i never see the image; before or after.

any thoughts on this would be great.

edit: so it seems that document.write is to blame. changing title to reflect this.

in case my original question was not clear, what i am looking for is to replace the image with the video, and then replace the video with the image. this is all loading in an iframe, so i need to use document.write (or something like it) to actually **change** the html.

Comment: @slomojo: Strings of the function calls will work fine as long as the functions are defined globally, which they appear to be.

Comment: Ah, I see it was the document write that screwed things up.

Answer (score 5):

Using `document.write` after the page has already loaded is a little weird.  That should only really be used for generating a page as it loads.  Try something like this instead:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function playVideo(){
        var str='**html of the video object**';
        document.getElementById('video-placeholder').innerHTML = str;
      }
      function backToImage(){
        var str='**html of the image**';
        document.getElementById('image-placeholder').innerHTML = str;
      }
      setTimeout(playVideo, 1000);
      setTimeout(backToImage, 3000);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="video-placeholder"></div>
    <div id="image-placeholder"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont think you understand. i want to use document.write to replace the image with the video. and then replace the video with the image. if i'm reading this correctly, this will simply show them both.

Comment: @psolms, you can us a single div and target it from both functions.

Comment: @gaby- ahhhhh.. thank you. i didnt think of that. @jacob- sorry if i misunderstood

Answer (score 4):

The most likely issue, is the opening/writing and closing of a document completely clears it, clearing the current timeouts, in the process, as well.

As pointed in [Document Object Model HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170)

> **open**
>       Open a document stream for writing. If a document exists in the
>   target, this method **clears** it.

This is how firefox implemented the clear part (*a complete clearing*)